# Can inventory plugin "constructed" create a groups based on ansible_facts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have plenty of EC2 servers in AWS and want to categorize them based on facts gathered from ansible_facts (by module setup). For example to have a group "CentOS" where `ansible_facts['distribution'] == 'CentOS'` and so on. But having file `inventory/constructed.yml`:

```
plugin: constructed
strict: False
keyed_groups:
  # this creates a group per distro (distro_CentOS, distro_Debian) and assigns the hosts that have matching values to it,
  # using the default separator "_"
  - prefix: distro
    key: ansible_distribution
```

I don't see a `distro_CentOS` group in the output of the command `ansible-inventory --graph`.

The plugin is enabled in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = host_list, ini, aws_ec2, constructed
```

How I can sort EC2 instances based on gathered ansible facts, avoiding the need to tag each instance?

Comment: what's the output of `ansible-inventory --graph`?

Comment: There is no group "distro_CentOS", as i said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `constructed` inventory plugin relies on already known facts. This means they either need to be variables in the inventory file, or cached facts.

Try setting up a simple local jsonfile cache. Take a look at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html or just add something similar to this to your `ansible.cfg` file:

```
[defaults]
fact_caching = jsonfile
gathering = smart
fact_caching_timeout = 600
fact_caching_connection = /home/<user>/facts_cache
```

Next, run an ad-hoc command across all hosts to collect facts:

```
ansible all -m setup
```

Now try and list your inventory again. You should see the auto generated groups based on `ansible_distribution`

Note that when the facts cache timeout is reached (10 minutes in my sample config file above), the facts variables cannot be used with the `constructed` plugin, so you will need to collect all facts again.

Comment: Thank you Matt. My problem was in constructed plugin config file in inventory directory applied not last. I have renamed this plugin to let him be applied last and all works fine now! Because as docs says plugin configs evaluate in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

The inventory plugin runs before the setup module runs and can't rely on its output (the caching can change that)

The [`group_by`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_by_module.html) module seems to be designed exactly for this use case:

```
- group_by:
    key: distro_{{ ansible_distribution }}
```